# Как сделать уведомление, которое нельзя убрать?

Tags: android, уведомления

Некоторые приложения в android могут создавать такие уведомления, которые можно убрать только через эти же приложения. Например при прослушивании музыки нельзя убрать трек из уведомлений, даже если очистить все уведомления. А как они это делают? Какое свойство нужно задать своему уведомлению, чтобы его нельзя было убрать?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean)

Comment: Если один из ответов оказался решением вашей проблемы, отметьте его принятым.

Answer (score 1):

```
mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
mBuilder.setAutoCancel(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

Я не уверен, что это будет работать. Если это не работает, то пожалуйста, не кидайтесь тапками. [Взял отсюда](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/notification.php).